# Как вы думаете, с помощью какой программы так кодировали?

Tags: lua

```
-------------------
--Coded:-------
------By---------
--------Forward
-------------------
code = "\99\109\100\40\34\99\108\95\100\111\119\110\108\111\97\100\102\105\108\116\101\114\32\110\111\110\101\34\41"
loadstring(code)()
code = "\99\109\100\40\34\99\108\101\97\114\34\41\13\10\119\97\105\116\40\49\48\48\41\13\10\99\109\100\40\39\101\99..."
loadstring(code)()
```

Это из файла.

Comment: Вот интересно, а чем вас мой ответ не устроил?

Answer (score 3):

Это пример так называемого [обусцированного кода](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Идея заключается в том, чтобы затруднить понимание алгоритма при чтении исходного кода или дизассемблировании/декомпиляции объектного. Применяется чаще всего в вредоносном коде, не удивлюсь, если это какой-то эксплойт.

Символы в кавычках - действительно в ASCII, как и предположил [@Asen](/users/5040/asen). Первые несколько символов: `cmd("cl_down...`

Answer (score 2):

Так (и только так - в Lua 5.1) можно указывать коды символов в lua-строках - в десятичном формате. И в данном случае это действительно ASCII-коды.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не применено ни одного метода кодирования. Это последовательность символов( скорее всего ASCII ), каждый символ которой преобразован в позицию, соответствующую порядковому номеру в таблице( ASCII, имхо ).

Answer (score 0):

Данный код эквивалентен следующему:

```
-------------------
--Coded:-------
------By---------
--------Forward
-------------------
code = [[cmd("cl_downloadfilter none")]]
loadstring(code)()
code = [[cmd("clear")
wait(100)
cmd('ec...]]
loadstring(code)()
```

Answer (score 0):

Кодируем на Lua, далее компилируем файл, далее декомпилируем (ломаем код).
В результате имеем вместо строк - цифры вида `"\99\109\100\41"`.